# Populate array with random numbers in Julia: type conversion error

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I am wondering if someone can help me interpret this error message.

When running the chunk

```
using Distributions
mu = [ 0; 0 ]
cov = [ 1 2 ; 2 4]
c = cov * cov / 10;
d = MvNormal(mu,c);
mc_reps = 10
p = 2
q = 1
r = p-q
x = rand(d,p)
errors = [Array{Float64,2} for _ in 1:mc_reps]
for i in 1:mc_reps
    errors[i] = rand(d,p)
end
```

I am getting the error message:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Matrix{Float64} to an object of type DataType
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at Base.jl:61

Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(A::Vector{DataType}, x::Matrix{Float64}, i1::Int64)
   @ Base ./array.jl:966
 [2] top-level scope
   @ ./In[34]:13
```

Can someone help me interpret this error message? Thank you so much!

Comment: The expression `Array{Float64,2}` when `error` is first assigned is a Type and not a value. Perhaps `errors = Vector{Array{Float64,2}}(undef, mc_reps)` is the intended statement, which just allocates a vector of matrices... But a longer answer is needed.

Comment: @DanGetz thank you that answers my question. I am new to Julia. Is it possible to use the undef keyword within the comprehension? I am hoping to do this in as Julian a way as possible.

Comment: `undef` can be used only in the context above and not in a comprehension. But if the goal is not to do more allocation inside the `for` loop, then the `= rand...` should be `.= rand` or `rand!(...)`. If you make the code work, it will be much easier to give tips on making it more idiomatic Julia (because as it is, I'm unsure what is the desired computation).

Comment: `errors[i] .= rand(d,p)` generates another error: `UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
`. You can ignore the `x` btw, that was a mistake. I shall post an updated question tomorrow. @DanGetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a bunch of random arrays in a comprehension, the easiest way is to do this:

```
errors = [rand(d, p) for _ in 1:mc_reps]
```

Then you only allocate as much memory as you need, too.